# Mysterious different conversion to string[] of seemingly same input data

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

During investigation of some problem I found that the reason was unexpected different conversion to string[] of seemingly same input data. Namely, in the code below two commands both return the same two items File1.txt and File2.txt. But conversion to string[] gives different results, see the comments.

Any ideas why is it? This might be a bug. If anybody also thinks so, I’ll submit it. But it would nice to understand what’s going on and avoid traps like that.

```
# *** WARNING
# *** Make sure you do not have anything in C:\TEMP\Test
# *** The code creates C:\TEMP\Test with File1.txt, File2.txt

# Make C:\TEMP\Test and two test files
$null = mkdir C:\TEMP\Test -Force
1 | Set-Content C:\TEMP\Test\File1.txt
1 | Set-Content C:\TEMP\Test\File2.txt

# This gets just file names
[string[]](Get-ChildItem C:\TEMP\Test)

# This gets full file paths
[string[]](Get-ChildItem C:\TEMP\Test -Include *)

# Output:
# File1.txt
# File2.txt
# C:\TEMP\Test\File1.txt
# C:\TEMP\Test\File2.txt
```

Comment: Yes, I would say it is a bug that PowerShell builds FileInfo objects in different ways depending on parameters, see my own answer to the question for details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, I have got some clues (probably posting the question stimulated my thoughts). Yes, this is kind of a trap, not only in PowerShell (but PowerShell makes it possible).

Apparently PowerShell just uses `ToString()` for conversion. And it was a wrong assumption that `System.IO.FileInfo.ToString()` returns the `FullName`. Reflector shows that it returns the `base.OriginalPath` which is just what was passed in the constructor, not necessary a full path.

Here is the demo:

```
Set-Location C:\TEMP\Test
[string](New-Object IO.FileInfo File1.txt)
[string](New-Object IO.FileInfo C:\TEMP\Test\File1.txt)
[string](New-Object IO.FileInfo ./..//Test///..Test\File1.txt)

# Output:
# File1.txt
# C:\TEMP\Test\File1.txt
# ./..//Test///..Test\File1.txt
```

Thus, it looks like the first `Get-ChildItem` uses just names on creation of `FileInfo` objects and the second `Get-ChildItem` with the `–Include` parameter uses full paths. Is this a bug? It looks debatable now. It might be a feature, questionable, but still with some underlying reasons. I doubt, though…

Comment: Good investigation :) I would submit it as a bug, because imho `Get-ChildItem` should return the same objects not depending on the way how you called it...

Comment: Submitted as a bug 556004:
https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/556004/get-childitem-gets-fileinfo-constructed-in-different-ways-depending-on-parameters