# Converting Get-ChildItem output to string[]

Tags: powershell

I have a script that accepts a list of paths to process as an array of strings. I'm using `Get-ChildItem` to generate those paths. I've come across some interesting behavior in the conversion from `System.IO.FileInfo` objects to strings.

Example 1:

```
PS C:\Users\Nikhil\Documents> [string[]](Get-ChildItem .\GitHub\)
toc
toc-gh-pages
Publish gh-pages.txt
```

Example 2:

```
PS C:\Users\Nikhil\Documents> [string[]](Get-ChildItem .\GitHub\*)
C:\Users\Nikhil\Documents\GitHub\toc
C:\Users\Nikhil\Documents\GitHub\toc-gh-pages
C:\Users\Nikhil\Documents\GitHub\Publish gh-pages.txt
```

Example 3: (With -Recurse, so the conversion to strings is illogical and useless)

```
PS C:\Users\Nikhil\Documents\GitHub> [string[]](Get-ChildItem .\toc-gh-pages -Recurse)
assets
css
lib
_layouts
_site
.gitattributes
.gitignore
index.html
_config.yml
jquery.toc.zip
docs.less
docs.min.css
google-code-prettify
jquery.toc
lang-apollo.js
...
```

Example 4:

```
PS C:\Users\Nikhil\Documents\GitHub> [string[]](Get-ChildItem .\toc-gh-pages\*.* -Recurse)
C:\Users\Nikhil\Documents\GitHub\toc-gh-pages\assets\jquery.toc.zip
C:\Users\Nikhil\Documents\GitHub\toc-gh-pages\css\docs.less
C:\Users\Nikhil\Documents\GitHub\toc-gh-pages\css\docs.min.css
C:\Users\Nikhil\Documents\GitHub\toc-gh-pages\lib\google-code-prettify\lang-apollo.js
C:\Users\Nikhil\Documents\GitHub\toc-gh-pages\lib\google-code-prettify\lang-basic.js
C:\Users\Nikhil\Documents\GitHub\toc-gh-pages\lib\google-code-prettify\lang-clj.js
C:\Users\Nikhil\Documents\GitHub\toc-gh-pages\lib\google-code-prettify\lang-css.js
C:\Users\Nikhil\Documents\GitHub\toc-gh-pages\lib\google-code-prettify\lang-dart.js
C:\Users\Nikhil\Documents\GitHub\toc-gh-pages\lib\google-code-prettify\lang-erlang.js
C:\Users\Nikhil\Documents\GitHub\toc-gh-pages\lib\google-code-prettify\lang-go.js
C:\Users\Nikhil\Documents\GitHub\toc-gh-pages\lib\google-code-prettify\lang-hs.js
C:\Users\Nikhil\Documents\GitHub\toc-gh-pages\lib\google-code-prettify\lang-lisp.js
C:\Users\Nikhil\Documents\GitHub\toc-gh-pages\lib\google-code-prettify\lang-llvm.js
C:\Users\Nikhil\Documents\GitHub\toc-gh-pages\lib\google-code-prettify\lang-lua.js
...
```

The addition of a wildcard to the path causes the resulting strings to be full path names, instead of just file/folder names. Why does this happen?

I understand *how* I can work around this behavior and get the info that I need; what I'm interested in is *why* this is happening, given that we're just converting `System.IO.FileInfo` and `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` objects to strings in all cases.

Comment: Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2744637/520612

Comment: @C.B. thanks for that -- that is exactly the answer I was looking for. Can somebody help me mark this question as a duplicate of that one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysterious different conversion to string\[\] of seemingly same input data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744047/mysterious-different-conversion-to-string-of-seemingly-same-input-data)

Answer (score 16):

Logical answer:

You are casting the `FileInfo` objects to strings. When you do `gci path`, you have files and directories only from that folder. So it is ok to just convert to the name of the item.

When you are using `gci path\*`, it is across folders, and just converting to names is not valid, so it includes the path.

Depending on whether you want name or the full path, do this:

```
gci $path | select -expand Name
```

or

```
gci $path | select -expand FullName
```

Comment: That might seem logical, but the same thing happens if I include the -Recurse switch. So the output in that case is completely useless -- just a bunch of file names with no directory names.