# Powershell odd behavior with Get-ChildItem and wildcard in path

Tags: powershell

Windows 8.1 Enterprise

```
    $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
    Major  Minor  Build  Revision
    -----  -----  -----  --------
    4      0      -1     -1
```

Here's what I'm seeing. I have a file "commands2.txt" in a subdirectory "level2".  For simplicity it is the only file in the "testing" structure. 
Full path c:\users\chris\testing\level2\commands2.txt

Setup
from c:\users\chris\testing as current directory.

```
    $stuff  = gci c:\users\chris\testing\ -Recurse command*.txt
    $stuff2 = gci c:\users\chris\testing\* -Recurse command*.txt
```

So now,

```
    get-item $stuff
```

returns "get-item : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\chris\testing\commands2.txt' because it does not exist."  Note that "level2" is missing. Its looks like its just appending .Name to the current path.

But

```
    get-item $stuff2
```

Returns expected results of a get-item of a fullpath file.

Odd right? So here's where I get confused.

```
    Compare-Object $stuff $stuff2
```

Shows that they are different.

```
    InputObject                                                 SideIndicator
    -----------                                                 -------------
    C:\users\chris\testing\level2\commands2.txt                 =>
    commands2.txt                                               <=
```

But:

```
    $a = $stuff | select *
    $b = $stuff2 | select *
    compare-object $a $b -includeEqual
```

Shows that they are the same.
I know I can work around this by putting the "*" in the path.

But why are the variables different, and how can I tell?

Why is the InputObject different?

Is there a way to see the difference between the two variables $stuff and $stuff2?

Update: Vesper basically nailed it.  Searching here with get-childitem and tostring returned helpful questions. Mine appears to be a variation of a few others.  [Mysterious different conversion to string[] of seemingly same input data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744047/mysterious-different-conversion-to-string-of-seemingly-same-input-data/2744637#answer-2744637) shows whats going on. In addition there is a bug report from 2010 here :https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/556004/get-childitem-gets-fileinfo-constructed-in-different-ways-depending-on-parameters
based on that previous link. Good times.

Comment: You should use `get-item $stuff.FullName` or `get-item $stuff.PSPath`, not just `get-item $stuff`.

Comment: I would say that is a bug since behavior is inconsistent.

Comment: @Petseral   Yes, I can do that.  I can also do $stuff  = (gci c:\users\chris\testing\ -Recurse command*.txt).fullname. It's not the fixing it that's the issue, it's "why is it doing it?", and "how can you see the actual difference between the two?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is really subtle, you can differ them via their `toString()` result.

```
 PS > $stuff.toString()
 commands2.txt    
 PS > $stuff2.toString()
 C:\users\chris\testing\level2\commands2.txt
```

Threre is some data on MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-lang=csharp) which indicates that `toString()` does not consistently return full name of the file. You seemed to have hit this issue. I say it's a bug, but there is a way to find if the bug did proc, by querying `toString()` and checking against `fullName`.

```
 if ($stuff.toString() -ne $stuff.fullName) { Write-Host "Bug!" }
```

Comment: The tostring() was what I needed! I'm still not happy about it, and its a pain that you can't easily expose all of the properties of a variable for comparison. Thanks.